# Importing 256 x 256 .txt or .csv (with many columns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file with 256 rows and 256 columns, which I exported from ZEMAX. I would like to manipulate the floats in an array in python.
When I import the txt-file with loadtxt or open or pandas I get an array of 256x1, where all the columns are within one column:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('TEST.csv', sep=' ',header=None)
df.reset_index().values
df.values
```

I would like to get access to the different columns, though. I just cannot find a way to do it! I should get an array 256 x 256 with float entries.
Do you know a way?

Comment: the entries in the .txt file are space separated

Comment: For example:  data = [1.1 2.3 4.5 5.6 ..., 3.4 2.1 5.7. 8.7 ..., ...]

Comment: Could you past few lines of the raw csv file and rather paste it in question as an update than in commets?

Comment: It's possible that your txt file has no carriage returns, it is in fact a flat array, which means you may need to reshape the data once loaded. Could you try after loading this `df = df.value.reshape(256,256)` this will give you a numpy array though